# Remove Text In Front of IP

Tags: php, html, vb.net, ip

I'm trying to make a Skype resolver and I have an API for it already, now all my code is working and everything, but instead of just displaying their IP it displays some html code in front of it, for example: `<h1><b>ï»¿0.0.0.0</b></h1>`, how would I remove the random text from the text box, also this resolver is made in Visual Basic! Here is the code I use to resolve if that helps:

```
Try
    DownloadResponse = GetResponse.DownloadString("http://SKYPEAPIHERE.com/&name=" & TextBox7.Text)
    FormatResponse = DownloadResponse.Split(New Char() {ControlChars.Lf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    TextBox8.Text = FormatResponse(0)
    Dim sText() As String
    sText = Split(TextBox8.Text, ":")
    If sText(0) = "168.63.55.14" Then
        TextBox8.Text = "IP Not Found"
        ListBox1.Items.Add("SKYPE RESOLVER: IP Not Found")
    Else
        TextBox8.Text = sText(-2)
        ListBox1.Items.Add("SKYPE RESOLVER: Resolved " + TextBox7.Text + " - " + TextBox8.Text)
    End If
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

If anyone can help me with this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Anyone? I still need help...

Answer (score 2):

How about using a regex to match the IPv4 format?

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("^([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})$")
Dim match As Match = regex.Match("<h1><b>ï»¿0.0.0.0</b></h1>")
If match.Success Then
    sText=match.Value
End If
```

Above is untested but hopefully points you in the right direction.

http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/318-how-to-match-ipv4-addresses-with-regular-expressions/